# Transaction aborted in event system

Tags: event-system, 2013-sp1, tom.net

We have implemented event system code which will:

> parse css files for images and replace image url with stub component
>   ids.

The processing was working fine however we started getting transaction aborted error from today morning. Can you please suggest what should be done to resolve this issue?

> Event System Exception at 'OnTBBCheckIn-10'. Error: The transaction
>   has aborted. Transaction Timeout   Component:
>   Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 0 User: NT
>   AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSubscription.DeliverEvent(IEnumerable`1
>   subjects, TcmEventArgs eventArgs, EventPhases phase)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSystem.DeliverEvent(IEnumerable`1
>   subjects, TcmEventArgs eventArgs, EventDeliveryPhase deliveryPhase)
>   at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSystem.DeliverEvent(IdentifiableObject
>   subject, TcmEventArgs eventArgs, EventDeliveryPhase deliveryPhase)
>   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs
>   eventArgs)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save(Boolean
>   checkInAfterSave)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.Update(IdentifiableObjectData
>   deltaData, ReadOptions readBackOptions)    at SyncInvokeUpdate(Object
>   , Object[] , Object[] )    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

Comment: Please share code. This error means nothing without context of your code

Comment: What's going on here? Event System Exception at 'OnTBBCheckIn-10'.

Comment: As Nick suggests - you should share the relevant code to give your questions context (this is noted on a few of your other questions also). If the code hasn't changed and this suddenly started happening could this simply be Network related and the request is timing out (I note you've posted other questions such as http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5108/cme-query-time-expired-for-cme-search that seem to relate to Network issues)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the problem was, the css processing logic was taking more than minute when it was giving transaction aborted error. On next day when I tried, it took less than a minute and transaction was successful.

So I am thinking it is the timeout issue however I was not able to get much details around it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you storing your CSS content as TBBs? If not I would dare to venture a guess that this error is not related to your problem...

If not:
Also your problem states it is a timeout; could the problem be that the content of the CSS has increased (number of image references) causing code to execute for longer than the configured timeout period?
Or maybe images were removed and can no longer be found causing exceptions in the code which are slower to process than 'hits' on actual components?

Last but not least I find the solution for the problem to be somewhat uncommon; why not have image references in the CSS resolved at publish time instead of checkin time? You would have the advantage of debugging your template in template builder instead of the much more obscure errors happening in the event system...